# como hacer un conteo SQL con las sentencia CASE when case

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ssms

Tengo una duda sobre como hacer una consulta.
Tengo el Case when, si lo hace como lo necesito, solo que también necesito que me cuente las solicitudes de ID_Solicitud , alguien que me explique como hacerlo donde insertar el count y me haga las dos cosas a la vez.
De resultado quiero algo similiar :

```
-------------------------
solicitudes|     año
-------------------------
3          | año anterior
```

---

```
select
    count (Id_solicitud) ,
    CASE
        when fecha_registrada >=DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,491,GETDATE()),0) and
fecha_registrada <=DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,129,GETDATE()),1)  
        then  (select Descripcion from CAT_Periodo
            where id_periodo=23)
    end  as año 
 from LIT_SRCartera
 where fecha_registrada is not null
 group by fecha_registrada
```

Quiero que me salga de resultado el conteo  de las solicitudes.No quiero que salgan Por separado como lo muestra la imagen:

[image]

Comment: Que datos de entrada tenes? estas agrupando por fecha registrada.. En la fecha figura la hora? porque de ser asi, no los va a agrupar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que no estás agrupando por la columna apropiada, lo está haciendo por `fecha_registrada`, cada una de estas será un grupo o fila distinta, de ahí que veas repeticiones. El agrupamiento, lo deberías hacer por la columna `año`, el único tema, que ésta es una columna calculada y no física, por lo que no puedes usar directamente el nombre `año` ya que el motor define este nombre recién cuando ya se completo el resultado final de la consulta (luego del `group by`). Un alternativa es la que ya te indicaron, en una respuesta anterior, se trata del uso de lo que se conoce como [`common table expresion`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/warnov/2010/12/12/cte-common-table-expressions-sql-server-2008/), es una forma bastante cómoda de resolver el problema. Sin embargo puedes hacerlo también sin recurrir a esto, simplemente copiando la definición de la columna dinámica en el `group by`:

```
select  count(Id_solicitud),
    CASE when fecha_registrada >= DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,491,GETDATE()),0) and fecha_registrada <=DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,129,GETDATE()),1)  
            then  (select Descripcion from CAT_Periodo where id_periodo=23)
    end  as año 
    from LIT_SRCartera L
    where fecha_registrada is not null
    group by CASE when fecha_registrada >= DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,491,GETDATE()),0) and fecha_registrada <=DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,129,GETDATE()),1)  
                then  (select Descripcion from CAT_Periodo where id_periodo=23)
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
t1.Año,
sum(t1.Cantidad) as Total
from 
( 
  select
    count (Id_solicitud) as Cantidad,
    CASE
        when fecha_registrada >=DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,491,GETDATE()),0) and
         fecha_registrada <=DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,129,GETDATE()),1)  
        then  (select Descripcion from CAT_Periodo
            where id_periodo=23)
    end  as año 
 from LIT_SRCartera
 where fecha_registrada is not null
 group by fecha_registrada
) as T1
group by t1.Año
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco hermano me salvaste de algo que ya llevo tiempo buscándolo, inicio con esto de base de datos, de nuevo muchas gracias.

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió, cualquier duda estamos para ayudarte. Saludos